ValueError: Shapes (None, 5754, 4) and (None, 360, 4) are incompatible in my CNN
I'm trying to train a CNN for movement classification using acceleration data. The shapes of my X_train data and my Y_train data are:
Train data shape: (637, 5754, 96)
Train labels shape: (637, 5754, 4)

And this is my code:
model = Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv1D(512, 3, strides=1, activation='tanh', padding='same', input_shape=(5754, 96)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))

model.add(layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(512, 3, strides=1, activation='tanh', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(256, 3, strides=1, activation='tanh', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None, padding='same'))

model.add(layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(128, 3, strides=1, activation='tanh', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None, padding='same'))

model.add(layers.Conv1D(64, 3, strides=1, activation='tanh', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None, padding='same'))

model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(Dense(4, activation='softmax')))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=2000, batch_size=16, verbose=2)

The error I get when I try to execute it, is: ValueError: Shapes (None, 5754, 4) and (None, 360, 4) are incompatible
This is the model summary:
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d_10 (Conv1D)          (None, 5754, 512)         147968    
                                                                 
 dropout_6 (Dropout)         (None, 5754, 512)         0         
                                                                 
 average_pooling1d_8 (Averag  (None, 2877, 512)        0         
 ePooling1D)                                                     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_4 (Batc  (None, 2877, 512)        2048      
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 conv1d_11 (Conv1D)          (None, 2877, 512)         786944    
                                                                 
 conv1d_12 (Conv1D)          (None, 2877, 256)         393472    
                                                                 
 dropout_7 (Dropout)         (None, 2877, 256)         0         
                                                                 
 average_pooling1d_9 (Averag  (None, 1439, 256)        0         
 ePooling1D)                                                     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_5 (Batc  (None, 1439, 256)        1024      
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 conv1d_13 (Conv1D)          (None, 1439, 128)         98432     
                                                                 
 dropout_8 (Dropout)         (None, 1439, 128)         0         
                                                                 
 average_pooling1d_10 (Avera  (None, 720, 128)         0         
 gePooling1D)                                                    
                                                                 
 conv1d_14 (Conv1D)          (None, 720, 64)           24640     
                                                                 
 average_pooling1d_11 (Avera  (None, 360, 64)          0         
 gePooling1D)                                                    
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 360, 32)           2080      
                                                                 
 time_distributed_2 (TimeDis  (None, 360, 4)           132       
 tributed)                                                       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,456,740
Trainable params: 1,455,204
Non-trainable params: 1,536

From the model summary, it is clear that each layer reduces the length of the sequence by half due to the pooling layers. I believe this is causing the shape mismatch error during training, but I also think that the shapes resulting from the poolings and the dense layer are okay.
I've tried adjusting the pooling layers and output layer configurations, but I'm not sure how to ensure the output shape matches the expected (637, 5754, 4).
I'm looking for guidance on how to modify my model to maintain the input sequence length through the network or how to properly adjust my labels if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
